# convert Crosstab query into new unique table that is still linked to the original table in ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have created crosstab query as follows:

it is the sum product among all records with the same unique id (query 2) extracted from "before group-by" query(query 1);

Query 1: this is the query extracts data from billdetail as it has no primary key
billhead_id  date     product_name  product_price   amount  total_cost payment_status
A1          1 jan 22  blue hammer   100             12      1200       paid
A1          1 jan 22  green hammer  100             12      1200       paid
A1          1 jan 22  red hammer    100             12      1200       paid
A2          3 jan 22  Arch200D      2500            5       12500      paid
A3          5 jan 22  Wrench        50              24      1200       paid
A3          5 jan 22  PVC fitting   3               800     2400       paid
A4          4 oct 22  struct. mortar80              78      6240       unpaid

Query 2: new query was created with "group by" billhead_id and others, "sum" amount from query1
billhead_id  date     total_cost payment_status
A1           1 jan 22 3600       paid
A2           3 jan 22 12500      paid
A3           5 jan 22 3600       paid
A4           4 oct 22 6240       unpaid

I created a new continuous form to display records from query 2 to attempt to "edit" payment status later in the future from the form instead of going back to the table or the form where I "enter" the data on its "arrival," and I would like to know what I should do to make this possible.
I apologize for my English. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't. These are non-editable datasets. Period. Open form to a record that can be edited. Period.

Comment: Use a tool to build markdown tables so your data can be legible https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables